# Evaluate $\lim_{x\to 0} \sin (\frac {1}{x})$

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

**Evaluate:**

> $$\lim_{x\to 0} \sin (\dfrac {1}{x})$$

**My Attempt:**

let $$\dfrac {1}{x}=k$$
As $\dfrac {1}{x}\to 0$, $k\to \infty$
Now,
$$=\lim_{k\to \infty} \sin k$$

Comment: Hint: Plug in the sequence $x_n=2/(n\pi)$ for $x$ and check what happens when $n\to\infty$.

Comment: You are correct so far. Now all you have to notice is that the function $\sin(k)$ oscillates between $-1$ and $1$. Regardless of how far you go out, it will keep oscillating and will never approach one value. Therefore, the limit doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: you can consider the sequences $x_n = \frac{2}{n\pi}$, or $x_n=\frac{2}{4(n+1)\pi}$, or $x_n=\frac{2}{4(n-1)\pi}$ when $n\to \infty$.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in your reasoning thus far. You can observe that the limit of $\sin x$ as $x$ approaches infinity doesn't exist, and neither does this limit.